# Maintain navigation item button alignment in SwiftUI as second button is added & removed

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13, ios-navigationview, navigationbaritems

I have a scenario where there will be one or two trailing buttons based upon some criteria. I would like to have it such that the buttons always align to trailing for visual consistency, but so far, they appear to center align, regardless of what I do.

Below is a minimum example showing this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isButtonShown = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isButtonShown.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text(self.isButtonShown ? "Hide Button" : "Show Button")
                     })
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    HStack {
                        if self.isButtonShown {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("A tapped")
                            }, label: {
                                Text("A")
                            })
                            Spacer(minLength: 30)
                        }

                        Button(action: {
                            print("B tapped")
                        }, label: {
                            Text("B")
                        })
                    }
                    .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                )
        }
    }
}
```

And a video that shows what happens when I select the button.

[image]

My goal is to have B remain in the same position, regardless of whether or not A is shown.

Finally, I tried a few other items:

- Moved `.frame(alignment: .trailing)` to the `NavigationView` level
- Added an `else` after `self.isButtonShown` that added a `Spacer()`
- Applied `.frame(alignment: .trailing)` to the B `Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is know issue in SwiftUI 1.0

**SwiftUI 2.0**

The solution based on new `.toolbar` does not have it. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isButtonShown = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isButtonShown.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text(self.isButtonShown ? "Hide Button" : "Show Button")
                     })
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    if self.isButtonShown {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("A tapped")
                        }, label: {
                            Text("A")
                        })
                    }
                }

                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("B tapped")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("B")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```